# RMarkdown table does not reduce size with kable_styling

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, kable, kableextra

When I use the following code:

```
library(data.table)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

DT <- data.table(year = 1:30, height = 1:30, weight = 1:30)
kable(DT, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))
```

The generated PDF spans the entire and cuts off at year = 8 or so. Interestingly the "striped" part works but it seems that the "scale_down" portion is not working.

I am using TeXLive, R Studio Version 1.4.1106 and my sessioninfo is:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.4    bookdown_0.21     htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.0.4       yaml_2.2.1       
 [6] rmarkdown_2.7     knitr_1.31        xfun_0.21         digest_0.6.27     pacman_0.5.1     
[11] rlang_0.4.10      evaluate_0.14
```

Finally, my preamble looks like the following:

```
title: "Title "
author: 
  - X
  - Y
geometry: margin = 1.5cm
header-includes:
     - \usepackage{booktabs}
     - \usepackage{mathpazo}
     - \usepackage{float}
     - \usepackage{geometry}
  
     
output: 
    bookdown::pdf_document2:
      toc: false

fontsize: 12pt
```

Comment: Could you please share an image of your output?

Comment: @bttomio the pdf looks like this (https://imgur.com/a/AYnUV3s). It fills up the entire page. Interestingly when I get rid of the "scaled_down" it looks like this (https://imgur.com/a/phKutaT). So maybe there is a problem if the "scale_down" is unncessary?

Comment: `scale_down` controls the width, not the height (check the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.3.4/topics/kable_styling)). Could you please clarify your question? In order to control the height, you may change the font size in `kable_styling`. Please check the link I just provided.